# DAV SVN config for server hosting multiple domains

Tags: svn, apache2, virtualhost, mod-dav-svn

I have an apache2 webserver configured to serve multiple domains (I did it with virtual hosts).

After installing Subversion and enabling DAV SVN, the repository can be accessed through all the domains configured. How can I enable svn access for one domain only?

Examples: 
  In dav_svn.conf the Location points to /svn, meaning that www.domain1.com/svn/ and www.domain2.com/svn/ will both give access to the Subversion server. I only want to access it from www.domain1.com/svn/.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Read the manual. You have to add your configuration in a ghost specific container

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic subversion repos via subdomains (in Apache)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448275/dynamic-subversion-repos-via-subdomains-in-apache)